# urdl and xacro files

Tags: urdf, ros-kinetic, hector, xacro, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

I have both quadrotor_base.urdf and quadrotor_base.urdf.xacro files in my directory. If I make any change in quadrotor_base.urdf.xacro file and save it, would it be enough? does the xacro file create a new urdf with the same name automatically or should I make anything else when I change a xacro file? As far as I know, urdf files can not be changed directly and we need to change the xacro file first.

Thank you very much for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350514/urdl-and-xacro-files/) by [jean01](https://answers.ros.org/users/53181/jean01/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> does the xacro file create a new urdf with the same name automatically or should I make anything else when I change a xacro file?

No, a `.xacro` file is just that: a file. It is not an active entity by itself. So it will not create any other files, or update other files.

If you want to keep the two "in sync" (ie: ensure that changes in the former appear in the latter), you'll have to *convert* the `.xacro` file to a `.urdf`. You can do that with the following command (after having `source`d the appropriate `setup.bash` file):

```
xacro input.xacro > output.urdf
```

This would process the directives in the `.xacro` command, evaluate them and output corresponding URDF elements. That output is finally redirected into a file.

> As far as I know, urdf files can not be changed directly and we need to change the xacro file first.

This is not quite true. You can edit `.urdf` files just as you can edit `.xacro`s. It's all plain text.

What you may have read somewhere is that it would be *advisable* to never edit a `.urdf` which was generated by a call to `xacro` (ie: the tool I referenced earlier), as that would make managing the two files more difficult: if you ever run `xacro input.xacro > output.urdf` again, any changes you'd made to `output.urdf` but which are not part of `input.xacro` would be overwritten (ie: lost).

So in general, *if* there is a `.xacro`, it'd be better to edit the `.xacro` instead of the generated `.urdf`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jean01](https://answers.ros.org/users/53181/jean01/) on 2020-04-25**:
Thank you for the answer, conversion from xacro to urdf works